# "Kochen beibringen" vs "*das* Programmieren beibringen"

Tags: difference

I found the following two sentences by searching online:

> Ich habe ihm Kochen beigebracht.
>   Ich habe ihm **das** Programmieren beigebracht.

I'm puzzled by the fact that one sentence includes **das** and the other one doesn't.

Is the **das** just optional?

In other words, are the variants below correct?

> Ich habe ihm **das** Kochen beigebracht.
>   Ich habe ihm Programmieren beigebracht.

Is there some succinct characterization of the verbs that one should precede with **das** in such a pattern?

Comment: _"Is the **das** just optional?"_ Yes.

Comment: Meint man das Verb, geht auch "Ich habe ihm kochen beigebracht." bzw. "Ich habe ihm programmieren beigebracht.". Dann ist das wie "Ich bin baden gegangen."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is almost to short to write as it is simple: YES. In this special case the article can be simply omitted.

I tried to find a reason for this special case with **nominalized** verbs, but could not.

There is even a third way to write all these sentences: You could use them with "zu" and an infinitive clause:

> Ich habe ihm **zu** kochen beigebracht.
>   Ich habe ihm beigebracht, zu kochen

Both forms are valid but the first one is not used that often.

Comment: To my mind, there are slight differences, but they are not easily put into words. Consider 'I taught her to walk' : [1] Ich habe ihr Laufen beigebracht ------  [2] Ich habe ihr das Laufen beigebracht l ------- 
 [3] Ich habe ihr beigebracht zu laufen -----  [2] seems to put more of a focus on the totality of the taught skill(?). Possibly the differences depend on context and inferred pronounciation, or something.

Comment: Muss das Komma in _Ich habe ihm beigebracht, zu kochen_ wirklich hin?

Comment: Das Komma ist an der Stelle tatsächlich optional aber erlaubt. Siehe [hier](http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/PartAdjInf.html#Anchor-Infinitivgruppen-47857).

Comment: `Infinitivgruppen, Partizipgruppen, Adjektivgruppen und entsprechende Wortgruppen können durch Kommas abgetrennt werden, um die Gliederung des Ganzsatzes zu verdeutlichen (§75 E2) oder sie als Zusatz oder Nachtrag zu kennzeichnen`